# Angular Animations not found for BrowserAnimationsModule

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-animations

I am trying to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` for my angular 4 project with the import line as follows

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

[image]

I have added the animations module in the project folder with the command

`npm install --save @angular/animations`

But when I see the `node_modules` folder, and then `platform-browser` folder, I don't see any `animations` folder which I guess is the reason I am getting the error for `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

So may I know how do I import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my case?

Error I get while doing ng serve

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart your IDE? Do you have any errors when running `ng serve` ?

Comment: Yes.  ng serve throws error. I have added a screenshot now. And yes restarting my IDE also shows the same error. I think may be the animation folder is not present. So that might be a case. I am not entirely sure though.

Comment: that is wired. i just installed the `@agnular/animations` in to the new created project and all good. What is your output of `ng -v` ? Seams you running pretty old cli version as I can tell by looking in to second printscrin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams like you are using outdated cli that already has being deprecated.
Try:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm cache clean
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Also make sure the you are running Node version `>= 6.9` and latest npm

If you need to migrate your existing app checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416430/angular-cli-updating-in-existing-project/45431592#45431592) and this [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) otherwise by installing latest `@angular/cli` you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure now that is the issue. I did uninstall and reinstall it. Now the angular cli and node is updated. And now I created a new project and it has animations folder inside of platform-browser.

But my existing project configuration had older configuration so still getting errors there. I will check online and try to update the configuration files and see if that fixes everything. Have a good day

Comment: My problem is solved. But It would really help me if you can guide me providing a URL or something which can guide me on how to change the configuration files for a project after updating angular cli and node js.

Comment: ok, but that leads to another problem, I guess one like Kiran Dash is having.

Running last command gives latest version of angular-cli (version 7) which makes use of `angular.json` which is somehow different than old versions of Angular where filename is `.angular-cli.json`. What if someone is using angular 2 in his/her project?